Get one value from the last row of a table, using an index
I have two tables, which are illustrated by the following example.
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   name      VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   status    VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
   CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

CREATE TABLE t2
(
   id             NUMBER NOT NULL,
   name           VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   finished_at    DATE,
   status         VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
   CONSTRAINT t2_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE INDEX ix_t2_last
   ON t2(name, finished_at);

Now I would like to get the values from table T1 with the value of the column status from table 'T2' for a given 'name' for the record that has the highest value in finished_at.
The following select statement is to illustrate the question.
SELECT name,
       status,
       (  SELECT t2.status
            FROM t2
           WHERE t2.name = t1.name
        ORDER BY t2.finished_at
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
  FROM t1
 WHERE t1.name = :name;

The actual question is the following:
Is there a way to formulate the statement in such a way that the index on T2 is not only used for a range scan with the name, but that the fact that the column finished_at is also indexed is also used?
The best execution plan I get is:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |      1 |        |       |     4 (100)|          |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |            |      1 |      1 |    31 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     107 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   WINDOW BUFFER PUSHED RANK   |            |      1 |      1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     107 |  2048 |  2048 |     1/0/0|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2         |      1 |      1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |   9999 |00:00:00.01 |     107 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_T2_LAST |      1 |        |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   9999 |00:00:00.01 |      67 |       |       |          |
|   5 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | T1         |      1 |      1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | T1_PK      |      1 |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - SEL$1 / from$_subquery$_002@SEL$3
   2 - SEL$1
   3 - SEL$1 / T2@SEL$1
   4 - SEL$1 / T2@SEL$1
   5 - SEL$2 / T1@SEL$2
   6 - SEL$2 / T1@SEL$2
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "T2"."FINISHED_AT")<=1)
   4 - access("T2"."NAME"=:B1)
   6 - access("T1"."NAME"=:NAME)

Of course I can create a different index, if needed. ;-)
Since there are many rows for a given name in T2 a range scan will result in too many buffer gets.

You have to create a multi-column (concatenated) index with all the columns you need, starting with name (equality predicate), then your date (inequality predicate), then finally your selected columns:
create index myindex on t2(name,finished_at,status)

The last column (status) is present not to facilitate lookup, but to put part of the table into the index so Oracle doesn't need to visit the table to get columns if everything it needs is in the index. This is called a "covering index" - it is "covering" your query so the table becomes unnecessary. Obviously you don't want to get carried away and add dozens of columns, nor do this all over the place, but for one or two columns to deal with a specific problem query if your query will run at a high frequency and needs the extra speed, it's a useful technique.
Now to get Oracle to avoid the sort operation requested by the ORDER BY, you simply need to ensure that your ORDER BY clause includes all columns left of and including the column you really need it ordered by. So in your example, you will need to do ORDER BY name,finished_at even though you are only hitting one single name. It seems unnecessary to include name in the ORDER BY, but this is what it takes to get Oracle to trust the sort order of the index as meeting your ORDER BY requirement and allowing it to skip the sort.
If you wanted the maximum date, you'd have to reverse both: ORDER BY name DESC, finished_at DESC and if Oracle didn't automatically do so I typically add a /*+ INDEX_DESC(t2) */ hint to nudge it into a descending scan (the default is ascending). But matching the ORDER BY to the index scan order is the key thing.

Beat me to it +1 ... note that your suggested index is a covering index, because it covers the entire correlated subquery.  But note that an index on (name, finished_at) alone might also be used.

@TimBiegeleisen  thanks for the tip, I remembered the language "covered" but not "covering".

A fiddle showing the index in action.

Well, better, but not exactly what I want. ;-) The TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID (Step 3) is gone, but the index is still used for just a range scan over the name. 3 - access("T2"."NAME"=:B1)

@D.Mika, the access is only going to show you predicates used for seek (binary search), filter for predicates used for scanning. Your date column isn't a predicate in your query at all. What your query should do is follow the index entries for the particular name in question in finished_at date order - since the order by matches the order of finished_at values in the leaf nodes of the index, it can dispense with the sort. Hence "using the index for finished_at" can only be seen by the absence of a separate SORT operation.

@PaulW: The main difference is the A-Rows and the Buffers column, that shows how many rows are affected by the range scan. At least the sql-fiddle still shows a WINDOW BUFFER PUSHED RANK

@D.Mika, ah yes, of course, I forgot something. i'll edit my answer to note the change you'd have to make to your query. I was focused only on the index itself.

Paul W put me on the right track.
I have adjusted the index as follows:
CREATE INDEX ix_t2_last
   ON t2(name, finished_at, status);

And the statement now looks like this:
SELECT name,
       status,
       (SELECT *
          FROM (  SELECT t2.status
                    FROM t2
                   WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                ORDER BY t2.name, t2.finished_at)
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
  FROM t1
 WHERE t1.name = :name;

This leads to the following execution plan:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |      1 |        |       |     4 (100)|          |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY              |            |      1 |        |       |            |          |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|   2 |   VIEW                      |            |      1 |      1 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN         | IX_T2_LAST |      1 |      1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|   4 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1         |      1 |      1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |
|*  5 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | T1_PK      |      1 |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - SEL$2
   2 - SEL$3 / from$_subquery$_001@SEL$2
   3 - SEL$3 / T2@SEL$3
   4 - SEL$1 / T1@SEL$1
   5 - SEL$1 / T1@SEL$1
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   3 - access("T2"."NAME"=:B1)
   5 - access("T1"."NAME"=:NAME)


Correct - note the absence of a SORT before (below) the COUNT STOPKEY. That means you are correctly leveraging the ascending order of finished_at in the index to grab the first entry and stop, avoiding an extra step to implement the ORDER BY logic. That's what you were after.
